# MongoDB, MapReduce and sorting

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb, mongodb-query

I might be a bit in over my head on this as I'm still learning the ins and outs of MongoDB, but here goes.

Right now I'm working on a tool to search/filter through a dataset, sort it by an arbitrary datapoint (eg. popularity) and then group it by an id. The only way I see I can do this is through Mongo's MapReduce functionality.

I can't use .group() because I'm working with more than 10,000 keys and I also need to be able to sort the dataset.

My MapReduce code is working just fine, except for one thing: sorting. Sorting just doesn't want to work at all.

```js
db.runCommand({
  'mapreduce': 'products',
  'map': function() {
    emit({
      product_id: this.product_id,
      popularity: this.popularity
    }, 1);
  },
  'reduce': function(key, values) {
    var sum = 0;
    values.forEach(function(v) {
      sum += v;
    });

    return sum;  
  },
  'query': {category_id: 20},
  'out': {inline: 1},
  'sort': {popularity: -1}
});
```

I already have a descending index on the popularity datapoint, so it's definitely not working because of a lack of that:

```
{ 
  "v" : 1, 
  "key" : { "popularity" : -1 }, 
  "ns" : "app.products", 
  "name" : "popularity_-1" 
}
```

I just cannot figure out why it doesn't want to sort.

Instead of inlining the result set, I can't output it to another collection and then run a .find().sort({popularity: -1}) on that because of the way this feature is going to work.

Comment: have you considered using 2.2 and aggregation framework?

Comment: Sorting currently isn't supported for an inline Map/Reduce (see [SERVER-3973](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3973) to watch/vote on this feature).  An inline Map/Reduce (or an aggregate query) is also limited to the max document size (currently 16Mb in MongoDB 2.0).  What is the issue preventing output to a temporary collection which could be queried in sort order?  Another option would be to sort the result in your client app, eg using [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

Comment: @Aysa: I have, but 2.2 isn't production ready yet.

Comment: @Stennie: Seems to be the case. The issue preventing me from outputting it to a temporary collection is that I can't have this feature creating a new collection for every request that comes into the app. The Mongo docs don't read like I can create a "temporary" collection anymore anyways. Of course I can delete it after I'm done, but that doesn't seem like a great solution. And I'm not worried about the 16MB document size limit at all.

Comment: @JonUrsenbach: The second release candidate for MongoDB 2.2 came out this week (rc1, following rc0 in mid-July).  I expect a production release isn't far off; would be worth testing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First of all, Mongo map/reduce are not designed to be used in as a query tool (as it is in CouchDB), it is design for you to run background tasks. I use it at work to analyze traffic data.

What you are doing wrong however is that you're applying the sort() to your input, but it is useless because when the `map()` stage is done the intermediate documents are sorted by each `keys`. Because your key is a document, it is being sort by `product_id`, `popularity`.

This is how I generated my dataset

```
function generate_dummy_data() {
    for (i=2; i < 1000000; i++) { 
        db.foobar.save({
          _id: i, 
         category_id: parseInt(Math.random() * 30), 
         popularity:    parseInt(Math.random() * 50)
        }) 
    }
}
```

And this my map/reduce task:

```
var data = db.runCommand({
  'mapreduce': 'foobar',
  'map': function() {
    emit({
      sorting: this.popularity * -1,
      product_id: this._id,
      popularity: this.popularity,
    }, 1);
  },
  'reduce': function(key, values) {
    var sum = 0;
    values.forEach(function(v) {
      sum += v;
    });

    return sum;  
  },
  'query': {category_id: 20},
  'out': {inline: 1},
});
```

And this is the end result (very long to paste it here):

http://cesarodas.com/results.txt

This works because now we're sorting by `sorting, product_id, popularity`. You can play with the sorting how ever you like just remember that the final sorting is by `key` regardless of you how your input is sorted.

Anyway as I said before you should avoid doing queries with Map/Reduce it was designed for background processing. If I were you I would design my data in such a way I could access it with simple queries, there is always a trade-off  in this case complex insert/updates to have simple queries (that's how I see MongoDB).

Comment: Nice workaround .. I didn't realise the emit keys would maintain sort order even if no explicit `sort` set :).  Wonder if this is an accidental side effect; the [Map/Reduce docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce#MapReduce-Overview) actually mention `sort` key as "Useful for optimization, like sorting by the emit key for fewer reduces".

Comment: This is not a Mongo feature, it is a map/reduce feature that applies to the algorithm, it *must* be sorted by key  (so it applies to CouchDB, Hadoop, etc). I've learned watching some video of Cloudera. As far as I see mongo's `sort` is only to sort the input not the output

Comment: This works beautifully. Not sure if restructuring this data, again, is possible so it looks like I'll just have to make due with M/R until 2.2 is stable and production ready and revisit with the new aggregation framework. Thanks again, crodas.

Comment: @crodas Actually sorting the input could be beneficial to MR performance [this post discuss about it](http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-speed-mongodb-mapreduce), and I tested in my analytics DB and it does help indeed (maybe not 6x as the article states). Cheers.

Answer (score 10):

As noted in discussion on the original question:

- Map/Reduce with inline output currently cannot use an explicit `sort` key (see [SERVER-3973](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3973)).  Possible workarounds include relying on the emitted key order (see @crodas's answer); outputting to a collection and querying that collection with sort order; or sorting the results in your application using something like [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).
- OP's preference is for inline results rather than creating/deleting temporary collections.
- The [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) in MongoDB 2.2 (currently a production release candidate) would provide a suitable solution.

Here's an example of a similar query to the original Map/Reduce, but instead using the Aggregation Framework:

```
db.products.aggregate(
  { $match: { category_id: 20 }},
  { $group : {
     _id : "$product_id",
     'popularity' : { $sum : "$popularity" },
  }},
  { $sort: { 'popularity': -1 }}
)
```

.. and sample output:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : 50,
            "popularity" : 139
        },
        {
            "_id" : 150,
            "popularity" : 99
        },
        {
            "_id" : 123,
            "popularity" : 55
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Going to go with Crodas' solution for now until 2.2 is production ready and then revisit with the aggregation framework. Thanks again.