# Mongoose MapReduce top values

Tags: node.js, mapreduce, mongoose

I have code similar to the example here http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.mapReduce

The main difference is that I'm trying to only save values which are within the top five.

For example, if the resulting mapReduce collection generates the following:

```
{
    "_id": "1",
    "value": 6
}
{
    "_id": "2",
    "value": 32
}
{
    "_id": "3",
    "value": 1
}
{
    "_id": "4",
    "value": 5
}
{
    "_id": "5",
    "value": 6
}
{
    "_id": "6",
    "value": 7
}
```

What would be the best method for only saving the documents which have a value key within the top five to the mapReduce results?

I've tried using the `sort` option but that produces this error:

```
[MongoError: exception: could not create cursor over [db].[collection] for query : {} sort : { value: 1 }]
```

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought maybe you should pass in a "sort" arg to your filter object, but then I came across this:
[MongoDB, MapReduce and sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015064/mongodb-mapreduce-and-sorting)

Comment: It might be a good idea to explain your answer a bit more (maybe include some of your findings from the link you referenced, etc.) :)

Comment: Good input. 8^) I'm new to MR but pretty familiar with mongo querying, so at first it appeared that the solution lies in passing to MR a query arg upfront, e.g. sort(); however, passing sort() inline is [not supported](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3973). The referenced link is less of a solution and more of helping to identify an inherent roadblock. The solution still aludes me, hence the M/R noobness, but personally, depending on time available, I might back out of M/R on this and go with http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/sort/#stage._S_sort